# propel building models in directories below expected output dir

Tags: php, propel

I have the following settings in propel.yml in root:

```
propel:
  paths:
    # The directory where Propel expects to find your `schema.xml` file.
    schemaDir: ./gateway/Propel/propelschema

    # The directory where Propel should output generated object model classes.
    phpDir: ./gateway/Propel/Model

    # The directory where Propel should output the compiled runtime configuration.
    phpConfDir: ./gateway/Propel

    # The directory where Propel should output the generated migrations.
    migrationDir: ./gateway/Propel/Migrations

    # The directory where Propel should output the generated DDL (or data insert statements, etc.)
    sqlDir: ./gateway

  database:
    connections:
      ...
```

I have the following in `gateway/Propel/propelschema/schema.xml`:

```
<database name="default" defaultIdMethod="native" namespace="Propel\Model" defaultPhpNamingMethod="underscore">
```

And this entry in my composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "Gateway\\": "gateway/",
    "Propel\\Model\\": "gateway/Propel/Model"
  },
  "classmap": [
    "database/"
  ]
}
```

When I run ./propel model:build I expect the models to be built in `./gateway/Propel/Model`, however they are being built in `./gateway/Propel/Model/Propel/Model` but with the correct namespace in the files...

Not sure what is going on here so any would be great.

Can supply further details if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema.xml, use \Propel\Model instead of Propel\Model. This is a known bug with multiple PRs.